# Android Studio and Appium

Tags: automated-testing, appium, android, mobile-automation

I am trying to learn Appium for a new project. I read through the manuals and the official documentation and I have one question.

Most of the tutorials seem to focus on `Eclipse + Android SDK +Appium.`

Now, when I tried to download Android SDK, I mistakenly downloaded Android Studio.

Now, my question is- can we use Android Studio plus Appium? Since Studio is an IDE, I suppose it would allow this? Am I totally lost here or can I use this IDE for Appium testing?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need the Android SDK at least for adb, otherwise you will not be able to communicate with a device.

You are confusing the IDE either Eclipse or Android Studio and the enabling environment.

Just install the SDK, or check if it is not already installed since AFAIK it is now part of Android Studio installations.

Comment: Also, run the doctor (stethoscope button) and it'll tell you what's wrong/missing. The SDK should be provided with Android Studio, but can also be downloaded here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: About adb: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719077/is-there-any-way-how-to-install-just-adb-without-whole-sdk

Answer (score 2):

**can we use Android Studio plus Appium?**
Yes! you can. Lets break down things here:

1. Appium: A driver for your tests
2. Android Studio: A code editor(IDE) built for Android.

Consider the example of using the java driver for Appium. Now what we are really doing is running unit tests in Java. That's all it does at the base. These unit tests, are in turn capable of automating the android controls.

So when you say that you want to use Appium in Android studio, what you can do is create a new java module and start writing your tests in that. If you already happen to have an android project source code, then also just add that java module into the project and start writing your tests there. You can treat it as a normal java project and run the tests from Android studio run button, as you would do in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Appium test case via Android studio but first you need to configure Appium in Android Studio. To do that please refer my blog for step by step explaination with screenshots and you can download the necessary files [from here.](http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/2016/01/setting-up-appium-with-android-studio.html)